# Generate permutations from multiple fields (not using Python)

Tags: permutation

I'm trying to do this simply, using regular Unix functions (that I understand), and not Python (I think itertools could possibly get me there ?) which I don't understand. So: several small lists of inputs (separated by commas), which need to be used to generate all possible permutations. Example:

List 1: (I, You, We)

List 2: (want to eat, want to buy, want to steal)

List 3: (a banana, a hamburger, an icecream)

So there will be 3 X 3 X 3 = 27 possible outputs, which are:

I want to eat a banana

I want to eat a hamburger

...
and so on

I'm pretty sure there is no one liner that will do this, but is there a simple way to achieve it using simple unix building blocks ?

Comment: Generally questions about using shell commands is not on-topic for SO... May be on-topic on one of *nix sites on SE, but likley need to be more specific there too.

Answer (score 1):

While not technically shell commands, a Bash script can do this pretty easily with just nested for loops.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

list1=("I" "You" "We")
list2=("want to eat" "want to buy" "want to steal")
list3=("a banana" "a hamburger" "an icecream")

for i in "${list1[@]}";
    do
        for j in "${list2[@]}";
            do
                for k in "${list3[@]}";
                    do
                        echo $i" "$j" "$k
                    done
            done
    done
```

Comment: Thanks so much dscripka, works well (after faffing around for a while trying to get Bash to work on a Windows machine). Can't vote up becasue not enough points.